# Simple css question regarding padding

Tags: jquery, css

Im having some problems with my css on: http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fysiosteo/

Since some menu items have longer names, they get a new row, which result in lack of padding at the bottom. Is there any way to make all menu items get the same padding bot, regardless of if theres a new line or not? Or do i have to solve this with jquery? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove min-height and set a bottom padding different than 0px on style.css line 89.

This will obviously not give you menu items of the same height.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have

`#menu-main-menu li a { padding: 10px 5px 0 5px }`

You you are setting your padding bottom to 0 which obviously gives you no padding at the bottom, duh.

**Make these changes in your style sheet**

```
#menu-main-menu li a { padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px; }
.nav { height: 41px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using the height of the box to create the padding, you *could* make the min-height of the box smaller (to say 20px) and add 6px padding to the bottom to ensure you always have padding at the bottom of a navigation item.